# Avoid "this site can't be reached"

Tags: ssl, certificates, chrome-os

I am trying to access my own server admin https://mysite.tld:10000
I have my own certificate. Surely I trust myself.
I get "This site can’t be reached".
I tried unchecking "protect...from dangerous sites" but that didn't work.

Chrome OS browser

Comment: Protection is not about certificates. You should install your self-signed certificate into your browser certificate storage to avoid warnings like that. And read something about how it works.

Comment: @rush there's a comment below the next answer

Answer (score 1):

"Your site can't be reached" is the error your browser returns when the browser cannot communicate with a server at the given address.  In other words, there's nothing actually listening on port 10000 on `mysite.tld`.  Or it may be that your computer is not on the network.  It could also be that there *is* something listening at `https://mysite.tld:10000`, but that there's a firewall or something else blocking a connection between your browser and the server.

Comment: It is strange. That Chromebook was in the same network as another computer where I was able to access that URI